# Decimal logs in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to solve an expression in SymPy

```
lg(10/b^3) = lg10-3lg5 = 1-3lgb (lgb = 5 => b = 10^5) = 1-15 = -14
```

But then I try to code it like this

```
b = 10**5
expression = log(10/(b**3), 10)
expression
```

The result isn't correct.

Comment: What result does it give?

Comment: - 32,23619130/ ln10, but I expected to see the number, not the expression

Comment: Note that sympy internally uses base ```e = exp(1)``` not 10, so to arrive at the final numeric result you could evaluate it with ```evalf```, i.e. ```expression.evalf()``` yields ```-14.0000000000000```.

Comment: Just for curiosity: if you set ```b = exp(5)```, ```e = exp(1)```
and ```expression = log(e/b**3)```, then ```simplify(expression)``` yields the exact solution without any need for numerical evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the result with ten digits, and not the decimal logarithm.
[Documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#exponentials-and-logarithms) says,

> In SymPy, as in Python and most programming languages, log is the
> natural logarithm, also known as ln. SymPy automatically provides an
> alias ln = log in case you forget this.

You can divide result by log(10) or define your own function, like this:

```
class log10(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, x):
        return log(x)/log(10)
```

Anyway, to get the desired result, you should use either `simplify(expr).evalf()` or `N(expr)`:

```
>>> expr = log(10/b**3)/log(10)
>>> expr
-32.2361913019166/log(10)
>>> N(expr)
-14.0000000000000
```